# Unsupervised clustering approach validated using internal data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation

I have used mclust package in R software for unsupervised clustering approach and choosing the clustering result according to the minimum BIC value. Can I use the cross validation method and calculate brier score as a internal validation method?